# Button inside a slideDown div in jquery not working on touch devices

Tags: jquery, magento

I have an icon that when it's tapped will slideDown the ul element that contain a button. The slideDown is working fine, however, the button is not working on touch devices. Every time I tap the button, the div element will slideUp again. How to make the button tappable?

```
<ul class="block-cart">
    <li class="menu_right">
        <span class="price">$40</span>
        <div class="block-cart-content" style="display:none;">
            <p class="block-subtitle">Your Cart:</p>
            <div class="actions">
                <button class="button" onclick="setLocation('http://127.0.0.1/checkout/cart/')" title="Show Cart" type="button">
                    <span>Show Cart</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>

$('.block-cart').on('click touchstart', function () {
    if ($('.block-cart-content').is(":hidden")) {
        $('.block-cart-content').slideDown('medium');
    } else {
        $('.block-cart-content').slideUp('medium');
    }
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This may seem like an odd answer, but I have seen on IOS (if that is where you are having this issue) you need to add css `cursor:pointer;` to the `<button>`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the `cursor:pointer;` is already there. The problem occurs both on iOS and Android.